# what is BlobTransfer Policy in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

In ActiveMQ while using blob messages we use this as broker

```
String broker1 = "tcp://localhost:7005?jms.blobTransferPolicy.UploadUrl=http://localhost:7005/fileserver/"
```

Can anybody explain what is UploadUrl and why we need to configure for blob messages(we don't need to configure for text messages). Why it doesn't allow tcp protocol?

Answer (score 0):

So plain text messages are good and easy to use, but needs to be in memory at all times. It works well with a KBs of data, or even a few MB. However, sending very large files, such as initial data loads, large media files or BI data, is not nice to keep around in memory. There may still be a need to pass the message around, route/filter based on message properties, use transactions and similar.

Blob messages is an attempt to solve the need to pass around GBs of data through the semantics of messaging. The trade off is that you have to define a streaming based server somewhere that both sender and receiver can reach. It can be HTTP, FTP, a local file, WebDAV or similar. ActiveMQ comes with a HTTP based fileserver if you have no other file area around.